# Long multiple-selection drop-down menus with search for visually impaired

Tags: accessibility, drop-down-list

How could we support visually impaired people to select multiple values from a long list of options (a few hundreds options)?

I have tested some multiple-select search drop-down with screen reader (JAWS) but none of them works fine.

Is there an implementation of multiple-select search drop-down that works fine? Or should I use another input options?

Samples of Multiple Search Selection as seen in Semantic UI and jQuery:

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#multiple-search-selection
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: Is this a long list that users can browse and select multiple items from, or are the items hidden behind a predictive search field like those in your examples?

Comment: Users can browse the list. They are not hidden. But the list is so long that searching would make more sense than browsing.

Answer (score 1):

"Is there an implementation of multiple-select search drop-down that works fine"?

Is this for a web page i.e. javascript/css/html based?

If so I've used https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select on a couple of projects. It has configurable autocomplete, filtering, search, grouping, grid-based layout etc, with a long list of demos available here --> http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

On your specific point, a couple of related issues mention the ability to use screen readers and the developer claims to have fixed it, but this is one aspect I haven't tried, so I'm putting it here as a possible:

https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/issues/138

https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/issues/139

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using autocomplete, or do you want all the options to be visible?

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
http://www.bu.edu/webteam/clrux/accessibility/autocomplete/autocomplete.html

If you want to make all the options visible, I would suggest using checkboxes or radio buttons, and grouping them by topic. Be sure to use the for and id pairing.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: Thank you for the reference with ARIA. I opt for controls that allows multiple selections. What I want to implement is to allow users to choose 10 out of a few hundreds categories.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone arriving here more recently, W3C publish a set of gold-standard examples. While I would normally add the content here to avoid issues with disappearing links, it is a long set of documents with lots of code.

https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/